# Highlighting the SEND button in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have generated an `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send a preconfigured SMS message, and I now want to draw the user's attention to the send button.  The user has already initiated the "send message" process from within the app, but they must then press the send button within the `MFMessageComposeViewController` to actually send the message.  The send button in the standard `MFMessageComposeViewController` is "hidden away" in the bottom corner of the message body where some, not so tech-savvy users, struggle to find it (a fact not opinion, as I have had test users ask what to do next)!

Apple does not allow this message compose interface to be modified, except for certain exceptions. I have looked into the `UIAppearance` protocol, which provides limited options to modify aspects of the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, but the options do not apply to the send button.

I have looked into the documentation, and there are options to highlight or focus on interface objects using the accessibility options, but I can not find a way of linking this to the send button within the `MFMessageComposeViewController` where I have limited access to the UI components.

How do I highlight the send button within the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, or access the button so that I can draw the user's attention to it?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408511). Please direct discussions of whether this question is on-topic, etc, to the Meta post, instead of leaving comments here that will need to be cleaned up.

Comment: I doubt it's possible to alter the appearance of the Send button. The compose interface is executing in an external process and the security model doesn't allow your process to interact with it beyond the (minimal) APIs provided in `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Comment: there's a screenshot in the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller) article, maybe you could create a mockup of what you want to achieve?

Comment: The biggest issue the users were having was accidentally accessing the attachments tray, rather than pressing the send button (If you don't know then it seems logical).  The disableUserAttachments() method in the MFMessageComposeViewController class partially solves the problem, but as the post is closed, this will have to remain as a comment, not an answer!

Comment: @JonH, can't you show your own designed screen which will tell users to where to look in the following/next screen? (A kind of help screen in between) there you may set a boolean to decide whether to show it again or not.

Comment: As best I can tell, Apple's using that architectural theme of making certain things require explicit user action to happen on the phone... however, there might be a way of making an ALT interface that can send in IM, by way of their business offering. (Just a suggestion, that's why I don't want to post as an answer). I have looked at the entitlements docs and there isn't anything optional you can request to do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to directly highlight or modify the appearance of the send button within the standard MFMessageComposeViewController. This is because the interface provided by the MFMessageComposeViewController is not directly customizable and is intended to provide a consistent user experience across all iOS apps.

One solution to consider is to provide additional instructions or guidance to the user before they are presented with the MFMessageComposeViewController. This could include an on-screen message or tutorial that specifically points out the location of the send button within the interface, or providing a visual indicator such as an arrow or highlight box to guide the user to the correct location.

Another option is to present the MFMessageComposeViewController in a modal view controller and add additional instructions or guidance in the modal view controller.

Also, you can use the accessibility options to add a VoiceOver label to the button, which can be read out loud to the user when the button is in focus.

It's worth noting that Apple's HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) discourages from customizing the system's standard view controller. You should try to stick to the standard iOS interface so that the user can feel comfortable and familiar with the app.

Comment: After much struggling, I came to the same conclusion. However I wanted to keep the interface "clean".  The biggest issue the test users were encountering was the Attachments Button (and App Drawer), which looks like a send button in certain situations.  For the target audience, this was an issue.  The Attachments Button can be disabled with the 'MFMessageComposeViewController.disableUserAttachments()' method, and this prevents the confusion by only leaving the send button active.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the caveats mentioned Ali Murad, is it actually possible to achieve using only Public APIs.

To present the Compose Screen:

```swift
//
//  Messaging.swift
//  messaging-demo
//
//  Created by Faisal Memon on 21/02/2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import MessageUI

struct MessageView: View {

    private let messageComposeDelegate = MessageComposerDelegate()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentMessageCompose()
            }) {
                Text("Create Text Message")
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: The message extension

extension MessageView {

    private class MessageComposerDelegate: NSObject, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
        func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    private func presentMessageCompose() {
        guard MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() else {
            return
        }
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({ $0 is UIWindowScene })
            .first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return
        }
        guard let rootViewController = windowScene.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow})
            .first?.rootViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        composeVC.body = "Please ignore this generated content"
        composeVC.disableUserAttachments()
        composeVC.recipients = ["07896123456"] // use your number
        composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = messageComposeDelegate

        rootViewController.present(composeVC, animated: true) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0,
                execute: { composeVC.present(OverlayViewController(), animated: true)
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

To create the Overlay effect, use a custom UIViewController.  Here we show only the most basic implementation for brevity.

```swift
//
//  OverlayViewController.swift
//  messaging-demo
//
//  Created by Faisal Memon on 21/02/2023.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class OverlayViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    var nameLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        self.nameLabel = UILabel()
        
        nameLabel.text = "Please press the up arrow button"
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 300, height: 100)
        
        mainImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill"))
        mainImageView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 350, y: 325, width: 50, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(nameLabel)
        self.view.addSubview(mainImageView)
    }
}
```

It is a hack in the sense that it takes advantage of the special way in which Apple provided the interface.  The compose interface is in a sense an opaque implementation for which we have only proxy access.  But this allows us to do a double-presentation trick to overlay explanatory content.

The end result is the following:
[image]

Whilst this solution does not violate the letter of the guidelines, and only uses public interfaces, it does violate the intent of the dialog because Apple intends such a system dialog to only be customised via UIAppearance methodology.  The alternative they provide is that the SMS is created via a URL scheme.

This solution also does a double-present since we present the compose dialog and then present the overlay on top.  Such a technique only works by an artefact of how the System UI is built up, and could break in the future.

However, I think there is a place for this kind of hackery.  I think if your users have a cognitive assistance requirements.  For example:

- they get nervous when "sending" or "actioning" items from their phone,
- have trouble seeing icons,
- don't have the metaphors readily in their mind to understand the Apple System UI,

then all we are doing is providing an assistance and thus improving the Universality of our app.